# Function not working if it have parameter

Tags: javascript, html, function

After requesting a json data i run it through function like this

```js
request.onload = function() {
  var mainData = request.response;
  loadNavbar(mainData);
}


function loadNavbar(jsonObj) {
 length = jsonObj.catagories.length;

 for (var i = 0 ; i < length; i++) {
 list = document.createElement("li");
 span = document.createElement("span");

 itemName = mainData.catagories[i].catName;

 span.innerHTML = itemName;

 list.appendChild(span);
 nav.appendChild(list);

 console.log(i)
 }
}
```

the webpage return error like this:

```
main.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at loadNavbar (main.js:21)
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onload (main.js:12)
```

But after i change it to this :

```js
request.onload = function() {
  var mainData = request.response;
  loadNavbar();
}


function loadNavbar() {
 length = mainData.catagories.length;

 for (var i = 0 ; i < length; i++) {
 list = document.createElement("li");
 span = document.createElement("span");

 itemName = mainData.catagories[i].catName;

 span.innerHTML = itemName;

 list.appendChild(span);
 nav.appendChild(list);

 console.log(i)
 }
}
```

It work accordingly.
Can i know what i do wrong in the first snippet?

Comment: Could you share `mainData ` as well ?

Comment: both code snippet is not working uncaught referenceError:request is not defined

Comment: may you log the ```mainDat``` in ```onload```? in both codes.

Comment: There's no way your second piece of code could work that way. Do you have a gobal variable `mainData`?

Comment: i think you are wrong the first code may work but there is no way to second code to work.

Comment: And please declare your local vars (`length`, `list`, `span`, `itemName`) locally. At the moment they end up in the global scope. A behaviour that eventually leads to really funny bugs. Well, funny for people that don't have to debug them.

Comment: Did you check the response type? could it be that `request.response` is a json-string and not the parsed object? How does your request look like?

Comment: this is the[Main Data](https://gist.github.com/Jawkx/1a56b694d6c9f0ba8e6a9648bfd0fcd9).i have also no idea why second piece of code is working

Comment: i'm very frustrated right now [here](https://gist.github.com/Jawkx/f236154711345bfa033cd0514f4dd37a) is all the code html/js/json

Comment: just tested the [last gist you've posted](https://gist.github.com/Jawkx/f236154711345bfa033cd0514f4dd37a). code works flawlessly when I load the json from the same domain. If I try to load it from `gist.github.com`, the CSP intervenes and `jsonObj` is null. But your error, that `jsonObj.catagories` is `undefined`, that's something I can not reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the object you are passing to the function does not contain an array called `catagories`. I'm suggesting you have a typo there and it is supposed to be called `categories` instead.

However, more information could be useful. The contents of the `mainData` object, for example.

Comment: this is the  [mainData](https://gist.github.com/Jawkx/1a56b694d6c9f0ba8e6a9648bfd0fcd9)

Comment: To me, it looks like you are passing in a JSON array instead of JSON object since the string starts with square bracket `[` instead of curly bracket  `{`. Try switching that?